# What is the correct way to make a TcpListener handle connections asynchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, async-await, tcplistener

Sorry for the long post.  I would like to use `TcpListener` to listen on a port, handle the heavy lifting requested by an incoming connection in a different (background) thread, and then send the response back to the client when it is ready.  I have read a lot of the code and samples on MSDN, and come up with the following implementations for the server.

For all of the implementations below, please assume the following variables:

```
let sva = "127.0.0.1"
let dspt = 32000

let respondToQuery (ns_ : NetworkStream) (bta_ : byte array) : unit =
    // DO HEAVY LIFTING
    ()
```

**IMPLEMENTATION 1** (plain, synchronous server; my translation of [the code from this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx))

```
let runSync () : unit =
    printfn "Entering runSync ()"
    let (laddr : IPAddress) = IPAddress.Parse sva
    let (svr : TcpListener) = new TcpListener (laddr, dspt)
    try
        svr.Start ()
        let (bta : byte array) = Array.zeroCreate<byte> imbs
        while true do
            printfn "Listening on port %d at %s" dspt sva
            let (cl : TcpClient) = svr.AcceptTcpClient ()
            let (ns : NetworkStream) = cl.GetStream ()
            respondToQuery ns bta
            cl.Close ()
        svr.Stop ()
        printfn "Exiting runSync () normally"
    with
        | excp ->
            printfn "Error:  %s" excp.Message
            printfn "Exiting runSync () with error"
```

**IMPLEMENTATION 2** (my translation of the code [on this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx))

```
let runAsyncBE () : unit =
    printfn "Entering runAsyncBE ()"
    let (tcc : ManualResetEvent) = new ManualResetEvent (false)
    let (bta : byte array) = Array.zeroCreate<byte> imbs
    let datcc (ar2_ : IAsyncResult) : unit =
        let tcpl2 = ar2_.AsyncState :?> TcpListener
        let tcpc2 = tcpl2.EndAcceptTcpClient ar2_
        let (ns2 : NetworkStream) = tcpc2.GetStream ()
        respondToQuery ns2 bta
        tcpc2.Close ()
        tcc.Set () |> ignore
    let rec dbatc (tcpl2_ : TcpListener) : unit =
        tcc.Reset () |> ignore
        printfn "Listening on port %d at %s" dspt sva
        tcpl2_.BeginAcceptTcpClient (new AsyncCallback (datcc), tcpl2_) |> ignore
        tcc.WaitOne () |> ignore
        dbatc tcpl2_
    let (laddr : IPAddress) = IPAddress.Parse sva
    let (tcpl : TcpListener) = new TcpListener (laddr, dspt)
    try
        tcpl.Start ()
        dbatc tcpl
        printfn "Exiting try block"
        printfn "Exiting runAsyncBE () normally"
    with
        | excp ->
            printfn "Error:  %s" excp.Message
            printfn "Exiting runAsyncBE () with error"
```

**IMPLEMENTATION 3** (my implementation based on [the MSDN page for asynchronous workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx))

```
let runAsyncA () : unit =
    printfn "Entering runAsyncA ()"
    let (laddr : IPAddress) = IPAddress.Parse sva
    let (svr : TcpListener) = new TcpListener (laddr, dspt)
    try
        svr.Start ()
        let (bta : byte array) = Array.zeroCreate<byte> imbs
        while true do
            printfn "Listening on port %d at %s" dspt sva
            let (cl : TcpClient) = svr.AcceptTcpClient ()
            let (ns : NetworkStream) = cl.GetStream ()
            async {respondToQuery ns bta} |> Async.RunSynchronously
            cl.Close ()
        svr.Stop ()
        printfn "Exiting runAsyncA () normally"
    with
        | excp ->
            printfn "Error:  %s" excp.Message
            printfn "Exiting runAsyncA () with error"
```

Now, from my reading of the MSDN documentation, I would have thought that `Implementation 3` would have been the fastest.  But when I hit the server with multiple queries from multiple machines, they all operate at about the same speed.  This leads me to believe that I must be doing something wrong.

Is either `Implementation 2` or `Implementation 3` the "correct" way to implement a `TcpListener` that does its heavy lifting in the background, and returns the response to the client when it is finished, while allowing another client to perhaps also connect and start another task in another background thread?  If not, could you please tell me which classes (or tutorials) I should read up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right structure for the main loop should look like this:

```
let respondToQuery (client:TcpClient) = async {
  try
    let stream = client.GetStream()
    () // TODO: The actual processing goes here!
  finally
    client.Close() }

async {
  while true do 
    let! client = t.AcceptTcpClientAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    respondToQuery client |> Async.Start }
```

The key things to note are:

- I wrapped the main loop inside `async` so that you can wait for clients asynchronously using `AcceptTcpClientAsync` (without blocking there)
- The `respondToQuery` function returns an asynchronous computation that is started in background using `Async.Start`, so that the processing can continue in parallel with waiting for the next client (when using `Async.RunSynchronously` you would block and wait until `respondToQuery` completes)
- To make this fully asynchronous, the code inside `respondToQuery` needs to use asynchronous operations of the stream too - look for `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite`.

You could also use `Async.StartChild`, in which case the child computation (body of `respondToQuery`) gets the same cancellation token as the parent and so when you cancel the main asynchronous workflow, it will cancel all children too:

```
  while true do 
    let! client = t.AcceptTcpClientAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    do! respondToQuery client |> Async.StartChild |> Async.Ignore }
```

The `Async.StartChild` method returns an asynchronous computation (to be started using `let!` or `do!`) and we need to ignore the token that it returns (can be used to wait until the child completes).

Comment: Can you use `use client = client` instead of the `try..finally`?